# Two labels in one caption possible?

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, cleveref

In a lot of journals it is common to have single digit figure numbers and denote parts in the figures as (a), (b), and so on. I wanted to use a similar style. After reading the documentation to the `caption` package and the `cleveref` package I did not find anything similar. 
I do not want to break up the picture in two parts and use `subfigure` with two captions but keep it all in one.

Is there an easy way to realize this? My example looks as follows without the correct references:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  a \rule{10pt}{10pt} \hspace{1cm} b \rule{15pt}{15pt} 
  \caption{Common text here. \label{part_a}\textbf{(a)} Description of a. \label{part_b}\textbf{(b)} Description of b. } 
\end{figure} 

This should read fig. 0.1a and fig. 0.1b but it is only \cref{part_a} and \cref{part_b}.

\end{document}
```

This gives this output:
[image: output image]

Comment: I would really not recommend this. Not only you need to introduce two labels hence referring to words instead of pictures and artificial `a` and `b` characters in the picture , but also you would encounter many difficulties when dealing with the publication office. It's quite easy to use `subcaption` (not `subfigure` which is obsolete now) package, is there any particular reason why you don't want to use it?

Comment: @percusse: Science, Nature, Physical Review Letters use this style, so I do not think it is so uncommon for scientific journals. Subcaptions take up a lot of space compared to just writing a single caption. I agree that the `a` and `b` characters are artificial but they also appear with a subcaption, just not in the picture itself.

Comment: I've made up an answer without the extra captions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A small addition to Mico's answer with `\phantomcaption` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}            %For dummy images
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefdefaultlabelformat{\thesection.#2#1#3} 

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \phantomcaption 
  \label{part_a}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace{1cm} 
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \phantomcaption
  \label{part_b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Common caption here \textbf{(a)} On left \textbf{(b)} On right} \label{fig-overall}
\end{figure} 

This should read fig.\ 0.1a and fig.\ 0.1b, and indeed it now reads \cref{part_a} and \cref{part_b}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that `scrbook` doesn't need the `\crefdefaultlabelformat` command. I've forgot and used the standard `article` class.

Comment: That is very nice and exactly what I had in mind, thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

A good way to proceed, I believe, is to use the `subcaption` package and its `subfigure` environment. That way, you can assign labels to each subfigure (as well as, of course, to the entire figure).

Note that you need to assign a width to each subfigure environment. This could either be an absolute length, such as `3cm`, or a fraction of a document variable such as `\textwidth`, as I've chosen to do in the MWE below. If you two subfigures and want to maximize their possible size, you could give them both a width of ca `0.48\textwidth`, and use the command `\hspace{\fill}` to spread them apart. (You shouldn't use `0.5\textwidth` as there's some "overhead" whitespace.)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  a \rule{10pt}{10pt} 
  \caption{Description of a.} \label{part_a}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace{1cm} 
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
  \centering
  b \rule{15pt}{15pt} 
  \caption{Description of b. } \label{part_b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Common caption here} \label{fig-overall}
\end{figure} 

This should read fig.\ 0.1a and fig.\ 0.1b, and indeed it now reads 
\cref{part_a} and \cref{part_b}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted to avoid the two extra captions as this takes up extra space and looks strange if the descriptions differ significantly in length. Is this also possible with the `subcaption` package?